# `invalid signature` when trying to boot OSX's CLOVERX64.efi from GRUB

Tags: grub2, uefi, macosx

I’m trying to create a multiple boot situation using grub2.  Please forgive me as I am fairly new at this.  However, I feel like I am fairly close I am just missing the ability to boot from an EFI partition.  Here are the particulars on my situation:

- Ubuntu version 15.10 64 bit  on /dev/sba – **hd1**
- Windows 10 64 bit on /dev/sdc – **hd0**
- OS X 64 bit booting from an EFI partition. On /dev/sdb – **hd2**

**Each OS is on a separate hard drive.**

All boot perfectly fine *standalone*. i.e. (w/o) grub. 
I am able to successfully boot to both Ubuntu and Windows 10.  The issue that I am having is booting to the EFI partition on my OS X drive.
After extensive research on the Internet I have come up with the following grub2 menu for the EFI partition.

```
menuentry "OSX" {  
    insmod chain  
    insmod part_gpt  
    insmod search_fs_uuid
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 8366-0C13  
    chainloader /EFI/CLOVER/CLOVERX64.efi  
}
```

This is loaded into the `40_custom` file.  After loading this I then run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and then `sudo update-grub` the menu comes up fine but when I select the Yosemite item I get errors.

- The Windows 10 and Ubuntu items boot fine.
- The hd2 part 1 has a UUID of 8366-0C13
- The `CLOVERX64.efi` file does exist in that location.

If I run an ls command the partition and all the files come up fine.

The error I received when running the OSX menu item is `invalid signature`.  I tried changing the last line to `boot` instead of `chainloader` and then I get an error `you need to load the kernel first`.  I have researched the kernel and at this point I am not finding any answers.  This is strictly a test system so I’m not too concerned about crashing the system.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Just remembered that Clover is a Hackintosh bootloader not an official Apple bootloader and a Mac, what I expected when I wrote this answer.

---

`invalid signature` sounds like your OSX install expects a secure boot chain like Secure Boot on Windows platforms. I'm not sure if this applies here but usually `hfs-bless` or Macs `bless` command were used to allow EFI booting of non-OSX installations on Macs. Similar to how Linux Foundations preloader bridges the gap of an unsigned EFI loader, `bless` theoretically should enable the foreign loader (GRUB) to start OSX.

`hfs-bless` is available in the [Mactel PPA](https://launchpad.net/~detly/+archive/ubuntu/mactel-utils).

Btw. `chainloader` should be correct and `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `sudo update-grub` are the same, just do a `whereis` to find the path and look at `update-grub` in an editor.

Answer (score 1):

LiveWireBT is on the right track, but the answer is a bit different. Like LiveWireBT, I think this is a Secure Boot issue. The trouble is that, AFAIK, Clover doesn't explicitly support Secure Boot; and even if it did, Apple doesn't, so Apple's boot loader is not signed with a Secure Boot key. Clover works by launching EFI applications in a way that requires they be signed if Secure Boot is active, though, so anything launched through Clover will fail if it's not signed by a key provided in your firmware.

The easy solution to this problem is to disable Secure Boot in your firmware. With Secure Boot disabled, there will be no Secure Boot checks and everything will work. The trouble with this approach is that you won't get any benefits of Secure Boot, which means that malware could theoretically take control of your computer's pre-boot environment, which would be very difficult to fix. AFAIK, such attacks remain rare (maybe non-existent) in the wild, but they are possible.

A solution of medium complexity is to replace or supplement GRUB with my [rEFInd.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) rEFInd supports Secure Boot, but it does so in a different way from GRUB, so that follow-on programs use Shim even when they aren't explicitly written to support it. Thus, if Clover is launched from rEFInd, Clover will be able to launch programs that are signed with keys that Shim recognizes. For this approach to work, you'll need to sign Clover, Clover's drivers, and Apple's `boot.efi` with your own key, which will add some setup and maintenance burden.

The most complex solution is to replace your computer's current set of Secure Boot keys with your own set. This set can include Microsoft's keys, but it can also include your own keys, which you'd use to sign Clover, Clover's driver, and Apple's `boot.efi`. These should all then launch with Secure Boot active. You could boot through GRUB, rEFInd, or anything else. (You could even set Clover as your main boot loader and use it to select between Windows, GRUB, and OS X.) The main drawback is that swapping out the keys is a rather involved process. I cover it in detail [here,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html) if you're interested in trying, or at least reading up on it to evaluate whether or not to try it. Also, if you go this route, you may have to periodically sign updated binaries when you update Clover, the Apple boot loader, and perhaps others. This will add a small burden to ongoing system maintenance, just as in the rEFInd solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same on a BIOS boot system, and I encountered a similar error. Instructions and examples I found for this case aren't clear. Are you using the UEFI mode GRUB2, or the BIOS installation? The BIOS installation probably can't chainload into EFI. Something to try if that's BIOS mode: try to chainload a bootloader on MBR or partition. It's a good idea to install a bootloader on every disk just in case, if you're using a multi-boot system, BTW. I like having 3 bootloaders so I can switch easily when one goes down.